# How base object controls the camera in Panda3d

Tags: python, panda3d

I was toying around with creating custom geometry in Panda3d engine. And next code works 100% correct.

```
class FooBarTriangle(ShowBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self).__init__()

        self.disable_mouse()
        self.set_frame_rate_meter(True)

        self.accept("escape", sys.exit)
        self.accept("space", lambda: print(self.camera.get_pos()))
        self.camera.set_pos(0, 0, 10)
        self.camera.look_at(0, 0, 0)

        self._add_light()
        self._add_triangle()


    def _add_light(self):
        # Adds a point light
        pass

    def _add_triangle(self):
        # Adds a single triangle in a certain place
        pass
```

Mysterious things happen when I remove `base.disableMouse()` from my code. I expect my camera to be movable and appear in the (0, 0, 10) position, looking at (0, 0, 0). But, instead, camera is in the position (0, 0, 0) and I don't know where does it look.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens, because Panda3D has a default camera control in place (*the default camera driver*), if you don't call `disableMouse()`, Panda3D will not move your camera through calls to `camera.set_pos(x, y, z)`, but only allow movement through the specified controls as can be read up [here](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/?title=Controlling_the_Camera) and [here](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/?title=The_Default_Camera_Driver) in the manual.

You either have to write your own camera controller if you wish to be able to place your camera anywhere other than `(0, 0, 0)` through code or just use the controls indicated on the links above to move around the scene.